# Programmatically (javascript?) edit divs in open in Safari webpage (Facebook)?

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, safari

Okay so using the inspector in safari I've found out that all chat messages in Facebook.com are divs with class="fbChatMessage fsm direction_ltr" and data-jsid="message".

I want to programmatically find all of those divs on the open Facebook page and edit the text of them (my end goal will actually be to translate them, but i've got that part covered)...
How could I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery like this to find them:

```
var messages = new Array();

$('.fbChatMessage').each( messages.push($('this').text()) )
```

To change the content of a div you can do like this:

```
 $('.fbChatMessage').text('new text')
```

Comment: Wow thank you for the quick response. Do I not use the whole "fbChatMessage fsm direction_ltr" class name? What does that "fsm direction_ltr" part even mean lol? Okay so my last question before I'm all set is how would I execute this on an open safari webpage?

Comment: Out there in this code `class="fbChatMessage fsm direction_ltr"` you have 3 classes: fbChatMessage, fsm and direction_ltr. I do not know what fsm does but direction_ltr is used for languages written left to right, so you have to pick the class that is descriptive for your element, in this case the first one (pretty intuitive name also).

Comment: As for the execution you will have to load this page of yours into a div element and write a nice javascript that will read that and do the job of translation and replacement that you need.

Comment: Sorry... which page needs to be loaded in what div? I'm kind of a web development noob as of now..

Comment: You will have to make a page of your own and load this public Facebook page in a div inside the page you are creating (using this maybe http://api.jquery.com/load/). Once the Fb page is loaded you start applying the scripts that you need on that like in the example in the answer.

Comment: Oh. That makes sense. I imagine there could be problems with that method though. Because Facebook isn't a public or static page - its https where the user would have to be logged in. If I added the Facebook page into mine, the page as a whole would by in my domain, but trying to do work on the Facebook domain. Would there not be issues there?

Comment: There will be issues ... you will have to authenticate first. You said "open Facebook page" so i supposed it was public, but I misunderstood. You might consider using this documentation in your script http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Yeah by open I meant I wanted to find an active Facebook page in a safari window, with a user logged in, and continuously translate/replace their incoming chat messages...

Answer (score 0):

to find all those divs you can try

```
document.getElementsByClassName('fbChatMessage')
```